# Calculating exact fraction of months during period

Tags: excel, date, datetime, excel-formula

I have a list of periods (given by period start, period end) in Excel and I have to calculate exactly how many months (as a fraction) are during that period.

E.g. if given a period January 15th to March 7th, then this would be

```
15-01-2015 until 31-01-2015 = 17 days
01-02-2015 until 28-02-2015 = 28 days
01-03-2015 until 07-03-2015 =  7 days
```

Months during period = 17/31 + 28/28 + 7/31 = 1,774193548 months

Note that in this calculation, start date *and* end date are both counted as part of the period.

As the periods can be anything, then I haven't been able to figure out to calculate this with an Excel formula (or if it's even possible).

Any ideas?

Comment: Why would you want this 'exact' number? One way to simplify the problem would be to look at the difference in years and months to get the number of whole, intervening months, then it remains to add the fractions at each end. You can get the number of days at the start as the difference between the start date and 1st of the following month, and the end number of days is just the day number.

Comment: Are there two columns? For example, column A lists the start dates and column B lists the end dates?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well it's not pretty, but if you have a start date at A1 and an end date at A2, then:

```
=12*(YEAR(A2)-YEAR(A1))+MONTH(A2)-MONTH(A1) +
 (DAY(A2)/(DATE(YEAR(A2),MONTH(A2)+1,1)-DATE(YEAR(A2),MONTH(A2),1))) -
 ((DAY(A1)-1)/(DATE(YEAR(A1),MONTH(A1)+1,1)-DATE(YEAR(A1),MONTH(A1),1)))
```

The way this works is:

1. `12*(YEAR(A2)-YEAR(A1))`: Difference in year times 12.
2. `+MONTH(A2)-MONTH(A1)`: (plus) Difference in months.
3. `+(DAY(A2)/(DATE(YEAR(A2),MONTH(A2)+1,1)-DATE(YEAR(A2),MONTH(A2),1)))`: (plus) Day of end date divided by the total days in end month, calculated by the diff between that month's 1<sub>st</sub> and the following month's 1<sub>st</sub>.
4. `-((DAY(A1)-1)/(DATE(YEAR(A1),MONTH(A1)+1,1)-DATE(YEAR(A1),MONTH(A1),1)))` (minues) Day of start (minus 1 to not count that day) month divided by the total days in start month.

Of course you duplicate that for any set of cells...

Comment: @Ian - to match the calculation in OP. It's a matter of if you want to include both start & end dates or not. Consider that start & end are the same date, if you expect 0, don't do -1, if you expect 1/30 (or 31), you need to remove 1 day from the subtracted date.

Comment: Why are you minus-ing in the last step?

Comment: @Ian you asked that already and removed your comment, but my answer is right there :-)

Comment: I meant you're taking away the fraction of the start month rather than adding it.

Comment: Ohhh.. that's because I start by counting the difference in months. I then add the partial end month and subtract the partial start month. If the dates are in the same month, I add a (large) fraction and subtract a smaller fraction.

Comment: Ah yes, ok. Because step 2 is `+MONTH(A2)-MONTH(A1)`, which is number of whole months plus 1.

Comment: Also note that `DATEDIF()` can return the number of whole months  (or days or years) between two given dates. This could simply the formula a bit.

Comment: @Ian, yeah, `DATEDIF()+1` is a nice idea. Not sure it's better then `MONTH(A2)-MONTH(A1)` though.

Comment: DATEDIFF() handles the situation of 13+ months much more cleanly than can be had with MONTH()-MONTH().

Comment: @ExcelHero - (YEAR()-YEAR())*12 takes care of that. As I answered before, I find it more readable this way, but it's a matter of taste.

Comment: Like I said... much more cleanly!

Comment: @ExcelHero And like I replied - it's a matter of taste. I personally find your version less readable. Seeing it as (years + months + days fraction in the end - days fraction in the start) makes more sense to me.

Answer (score 3):

Why don't you use:

```
=12*YEARFRAC(StartDate,EndDate)
```

Answer (score 2):

Assuming column A lists the start dates and column B lists the end dates:

```
=SUMPRODUCT((1+B1:B3-A1:A3)/DAY(DATE(YEAR(A1:A3),MONTH(A1:A3)+1,)))
```

Note: you will need to increase the depth of the ranges to suit your needs... just change the 3s to a deeper row number.

**UPDATE**

Based upon your feedback and new requirement, here is a version of the above formula that will calculate the total, one row at a time:

```
=(1+B1-A1)/DAY(DATE(YEAR(A1),MONTH(A1)+1,))
```

**UPDATE 2**

Based on new information that the interval on one row can exceed one month, here is a new version of the formula:

```
=DATEDIF(A1-DAY(A1)+1,B1,"m")-1+(1+EOMONTH(A1,0)-A1)/DAY(DATE(YEAR(A1),MONTH(A1)+1,))+(B1-EOMONTH(B1,-1))/DAY(DATE(YEAR(B1),MONTH(B1)+1,))
```

IMPORTANT NOTE: After confirming this formula you will need to apply GENERAL number formatting to the cell. This is because Excel will try to apply DATE number formatting unnecessarily.

Comment: @pnuts Each month is self contained. In other words each month is on just one row... according to the example data. So a span across a year boundary should be no problem at all. Do you mean something else?

Comment: YES, it did! Wow! Only unexpected thing is that it calculates one fraction for the whole range of pairs, but I want it to be per pair (if I modify the formula to a single row, e.g. A1:A1 instead of A1:A3 then it gives slightly different result).

Comment: Hi, sorry, turns out it's not working correctly actually (neither version). To test, consider two periods:  01/01/15 to 31/12/15..you formula gives the fraction to that 11.77 while it should be exactly 12. Why's that? I thought it might be because you take the end period as excluded but even if I change the end date to 01/01/2016 it gives me 11.81

Comment: Are these dates on one row? Or do you have 12 rows involved here?

Comment: Yeah, they are on one row, meaning A1 is start date and B1 is end date.

Comment: Well, yeah of course it won't work. The formula is designed for each month to be on a separate row... like in your example. I'll rework it. Hold on.

Comment: @user315648 Please see UPDATE 2.

Comment: @user315648 What happened?

Comment: @ExcelHero hey, sorry to bother on this very old thread, but can you please advise as to why use DATE(YEAR(A1),MONTH(A1)+1,) instead of EOMONTH(A1,0) in the denominator please? It was a really helpful snippet and I've used it, was wondering about just that one bit.